# How to solve an unknown internal error in possible gradle in android studio, that is producing bad new projects and infecting previous work?

Tags: android, xml

For no discern-able reason, since today when I create a new project in Android Studio, every single time I get this

image showing how all new projects (basic Hello World) are being created by android studio. Please check this

[image]

Notable points are- 
- colors.xml is always blank
- D:\scodeapps\MyApplication3\app\src\main\res\values***colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.***

googling for this last line, an SO post mentioned "delete gradle caches".

Not implementing that, on opening an existing projects, this happens

the styles.xml is half-deleted,

[image]

and I don't know how to describe what happens to `colors.xml`, do take a look

[image]

Tried clean build and rebuilding.
Tried invalidating cache and restart.
Tried reboot

Then as mentioned above, deleted contents form .gradle/caches/

Yet this issue is persistent.

Any suggestions are welcome

**UPDATE 1**

I uninstalled android studio, with settings. Then reinstalled.
This changed my SHA1 key,
**but most importantly I'm not able to use views and their attributes properly**

when I add and edittext,  it happens like this

1. [(the element tag comes without the width and height attributes, like
   it normally does)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvUCv.png)
2. [and this image shows that even when I try to manually add
   attributes, they are SIMPLY NOT AVAILABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d747h.png)

Comment: try to re-install android studio, looks like your android plugin has been removed.

Comment: @KaranMer I just reinstalled it before posting this update. You suggesting I reinstall again?

Comment: can you check for updates and update if there are any?

Comment: @KaranMer I did that...there were for "Emulator, NDK, Google API System Image". Still I initiated the update. No changes

Comment: are you sure you are using correct versions make sure your jdk, android studio and os are similar i.e 32 bit or 64 bit. all 3 must be same.

Comment: yeah they are, been working on the same setup for last 3 months and all is 64 bit. It started acting up since 2 days back

Answer (score 0):

Wrap content your xml files into `<resources></resources>` tag. For example `colors.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <color name="red">#db001b</color>
    ....
</resources>
```

See [this article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-App-Resources).

Comment: I forgot to mention earlier, I tried manually adding normal colors in <resources> tags. Yet the effect is same. Further, did you see what is happening if I open old projects? That is more worrying