# Regular view's attributes not available in XML in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, gradle, attributes, android-view

I had a problem, which I sought to resolve by uninstalling Android Studio with settings and reinstalling.

Things looked fine and gradle synced successfully, but now I'm not able to access any attributes for the views.

- When I add a view, it gets added without the regular attributes
  (width and height), just as a tag, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYana.png)
- further, I'm not able to add attributes to it normally. For example, 
  **android:text=" "** tag is just not available and the available ones [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKDRa.png)

This has brought work to a full halt. 
Any advice highly appreciated.

P.S. I was getting a highly weird situation which I tried to solve by reinstalling android studio (blunt, but I couldn't find any solution after 2 days). This may be a side-effect of that thing. The description can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326689/how-to-solve-an-unknown-internal-error-in-possible-gradle-in-android-studio-tha)

Comment: it is showing the correct attribute. Just press enter

Comment: @VivekMishra hello, please look closely , "lhm", "lww" such is not how we find the attributes to be named. Further, I can't see or type and use any other attribute

Comment: did you read what it is showing on the right hand side in that suggestion view. After the update android studio is suggesting in the manner that is shown in the image